# Union sorting after ignoring some digits

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, numerics

I have a list with its bellow elements:

```
{-0.7071067811865476, -0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865476}
```

If I use `Union`, but there is no change. Because the numbers are different. I want to use of `Union` for keeping just `-0.707` and `0.707` and other digits after third (I mean ...`10678`....) are not important. How can I apply this aim in `Union` function. Is there another function for this goal?

Comment: Use `Round` before or put it as a test in `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: `Union` has the option `SameTest`: `Union[list, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-4 &)]`

Comment: With thanks to Kuba, but I think the second comment is more flexible. I have 200 lists, all of them are not similar and if I choose "round" I just have to select a number for rounding which is not useful for other lists

Comment: A comment in favour of rounding: using the `SameTest` option will slow down `Union`.  Without `SameTest`, `Union` relies on sorting, which is of $O(n \log n)$ complexity.  `SameTest` forces comparing each pair, i.e. $O(n^2)$ complexity.

Comment: A bit verbose, but could do `Union[SetPrecision[Rationalize[SetPrecision[list, 3], 0], 3]]`.

Comment: Alternatively, `Sort[Mean /@ FindClusters[list]]`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following shory code:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[lst,Floor[#,10^-4]&]
```

Will this help?

Answer (score 0):

Therefore, by all means, study all the answers in the comments assiduously. The Example @Daniel Lichtblau I like most.

But see also:

> lst = {-0.7071067811865476, -0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475, 
>     0.7071067811865476}

```
Rationalize[lst, 0.001]
```

> $\left\{-\frac{29}{41},-\frac{29}{41},\frac{29}{41},\frac{29}{41}\right\}$

```
DeleteDuplicates[{-(29/41), -(29/41), 29/41, 29/41}]
```

> $\left\{-\frac{29}{41},\frac{29}{41}\right\}$

Comment: Will DeleteDuplicatesBy be a better solution?